# Swift: expected declaration error with .frame

Tags: swift

Hey guys i am using the xcode6 beta 4.

Im trying to to give a button a size with the argument .frame but i got an expected declaration error. I hope you can tell me whats wrong with my code and why i get this error!

```
 var button1   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
 button1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 40, 145) //Expected declaration
 button1.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
 menuView.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: First off, you should really update to beta 5.

Comment: I will do it the next days. But I do not think that updating to beta 5 would solve my problems.

Comment: It won't but you're likely going to find that code you write today won't compile in beta 5 due to changes in Swift. So you're just compounding your work for tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be mistaken as to which line is throwing the error.

Look at line 4 in what you shared.

`menuView.addSubview(button)`

Shouldn't that be `button1`, not `button`?

`menuView.addSubview(button1)`

**EDIT**

As mentioned in my comment, you might be trying to access the `button1` declaration inside the class declaration, all logic must be within functions. Only variable declarations can be outside of functions.

```
class Foo {

    var menuView = UIView()
    var button1: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

    button1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 40, 145)
    button1.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    menuView.addSubview(button1)
}
```

The above is not ok, you can declare the `button1` variable at the class level but you cannot start accessing it until you're inside a function like below.

```
class Foo {

    var menuView = UIView()
    var button1: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

    func setupButton1() {
        button1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 40, 145)
        button1.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        menuView.addSubview(button1)
    }

}
```

Comment: I already changed this mistake but it is still the same error.

Comment: Ok so it's a scope issue. Where is this code in relation to the rest of your class? If this is in a function then it should be working fine. If this is inside a class, you need everything after the declaration inside of a function.